# How to escape white characters in C++

Tags: c++

I was trying to copy a file to another folder using the system keyword inside c++, it works fine as long as it doesn't include a white character

**So how can I make the "fix this" file copy without errors?**

```
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
void trial(){
//*"fix this" is the file's name that I want to copy*
system("copy fix this C:\\users\\public\\");
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Did you try enclosing the filename in quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ has almost nothing to do with this. Your problem is how to escape a space into a command fed into the Windows CMD shell; in general, the problem [is nontrivial](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html), but in this case you can simply surround the file name with double quotes, which in turn have to be escaped as you are in a C++ string literal:

```
system("copy \"fix this\" C:\\users\\public\\");
```

That being said, it makes zero sense to invoke the shell to copy a file - you have to deal with escaping, bad error reporting, spawning external processes for something that can be done already from C++.

Given that you are already in nonportable territory (your command for cmd.exe is not portable to other shells) you can use [the `CopyFile` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile):

```
if(!CopyFile("fix this", "c:\\users\\public\\fix this", TRUE)) {
    std::cout<<"Couldn't copy file\n";
}
```

Also, from C++17 finally [there's a standard, portable way to copy files](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/copy).

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes for path, `copy "this is long path with spaces"` or `system("copy \"this is long path with spaces\"");`